# Django database relation

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite

I am working on a forum using django, I have a problem accessing user fullname and bio, from a model class I have.  I have no problem accessing the user.username or user.email, but not from the Author class..

This is from the models.py in the forum app

```
User = get_user_model()

class Author(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fullname = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True)
    slug = slug = models.SlugField(max_length=400, unique=True, blank=True)
    bio = HTMLField()
    points = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    profile_pic = ResizedImageField(size=[50, 80], quality=100, upload_to="authors", default=None, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.fullname
```

My form is in the user app, where i have a profile update site, and the form is like this

```
from forums.models import Author

class UpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = ('fullname', 'bio', 'profile_pic')
```

Then here is some of the update site, however nothing let me get access to the bio or fullname, I've tried so many combos. and I am lost here..

```
{% block content %}
    <section class="section" id="about">
        <!-- Title -->
        <div class="section-heading">
            <h3 class="title is-2">Hey {{ user.username }}</h3>
            <div class="container">
                <p>{{  user.bio }}bio comes here</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Here is the view.py from the user app

```
from .forms import UpdateForm

def update_profile(request):
    context = {}
    user = request.user
    instance = Author.objects.filter(user=user).first()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.user = user
            form.save()
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = UpdateForm(instance=user)
    context.update({
        'form': form,
        'title': 'update_profile',
    })
    return render(request, 'register/update.html', context)
```

The form html

```
<form method="POST" action="." enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            {% csrf_token %}    
                            {{form|crispy}}
                            <hr>
                            <button class="button is-block is-info is-large is-fullwidth">Update <i class="fa fa-sign-in" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                        </form>
```

If there is some relation i am missing please help

Comment: Can you show the view where you pass the context to the template?

Comment: added the view.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view currently creates a *new* `Author` record each time you "update" the model. I would advise to first clean up the database and remove all authors.

Then you can convert the `ForeignKey` into a `OneToOneField` here: that way we know that each user has *at most* one `Author`:

```
from django.conf import settings

class Author(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    # …
```

Now we can alter the view to create a record in case there is no such record, or update an existing record if there is one:

```
from .forms import UpdateForm

def update_profile(request):
    context = {}
    user = request.user
    instance = Author.objects.filter(user=user).first()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=instance)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.user = user
            form.save()
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = UpdateForm(instance=instance)
    context.update({
        'form': form,
        'title': 'update_profile',
    })
    return render(request, 'register/update.html', context)
```

In the template, you can render data of the related `Author` model for a user `user` with:

```
{{ user.author.fullname }}
{{ user.author.bio }}
```

Comment: NameError: name 'Author' is not defined
Is this my author class from models that i have to import or a django class?

Edit: Yes it was, thank you :)

Comment: @MerrinX: yes, you need to import the model in the view.

Comment: Only problem i have now, is that it wont update the profile, when i try, it did earlier, but as you said, it created new record each time, but it did work, now i get no errors but it wont save the update

Comment: @MerrinX: are you sure the `else` binds with the `request.method == 'POST'` and not the `form.is_valid()`? Did you change the view, if so edit the question with the new view.

Comment: @MerrinX: does the page redirect to `/`, or does it render the form again?

Comment: I have updated the view.py and yes it redirects to "/"

Comment: @MerrinX: does it update everything but the file? Can you share the HTML `<form>`?

Comment: I have updated the form in the question

Comment: When i updated the user in my post class in models.py for my forum, same as the Author class, I do now get FOREIGN KEY constraint failed when try to post on the forum

Comment: @MerrinX: sorry, I made a mistake, it is `instance=instance`, not `instance=user` in the forms (2 times).

Comment: After updating the models.py in the forum, adding the new user as you instructed, i added it to the post, comment, category and reply classes as well as the author class as you instructed, and now i can only post one post per user.

Comment: @MerrinX: your `Post` should have a `ForeignKey` to author, such that you can let multiple posts refer to the same author. The `Author` has a `OneToOneField` to the user, since it does not make much sense that a user has two or more authors.

Comment: Check my answer to see if this is how you want it?